# AWS Lambda using Annotations framework for .NET - missing Role

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm porting to AWS Lambda functions an entire .NET 6 web application, using AWS Lambda Annotations framework.

With each build, the `Amazon.Lambda.Annotations` package takes every annotated API method and converts it into a Lambda function source code, auto-generating the `serverless.template` to tie it all together for Cloudformation stack deploy.

Everything works like a charm, except that the specified `Role` for the method isn't put into the `serverless.template`.

e.g. Using policy ARN and role ARN of existing resources on my AWS, an annotated method like this:

```cs
[LambdaFunction(
    ResourceName = $"GetThing",
    Timeout = 42,
    MemorySize = 512,
    Policies = "arn:aws:iam::11111111:policy/ThingyPolicy",
    Role = "arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/ThingyRole"
)]
[HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/GetThing")]
public async Task<Thing> GetThing() {
    //...
}
```

Is referenced in the generated `serverless.template` like this:

```json
...
"MenuItemAll": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Metadata": {
    "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
    "SyncedEvents": [
      "RootGet"
    ]
  },
  "Properties": {
    "Runtime": "dotnet6",
    "CodeUri": ".",
    "MemorySize": 512,
    "Timeout": 42,
    "PackageType": "Zip",
    "Handler": "MyProject::Controllers.ThingController_GetThing_Generated::GetThing",
    "Events": {
      "RootGet": {
        "Type": "HttpApi",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/GetThing",
          "Method": "GET"
        }
      }
    },
    //"Role": "<--- MISSING!!"
    "Policies": [
      "arn:aws:iam::11111111:policy/ThingyPolicy"
    ]
  }
},
...
```

`Policy`, `Timeout` and `MemorySize` are correctly referenced, but there is no trace of the assigned `Role`.

I specified the `Role` within the `LambdaFunctionAttribute` expecting to see it referenced inside the resulting Cloudformation template.

Unfortunately the `Role` is the only property not correctly translated into the `serverless.template`.

I tried directly inserting the `Role` property into the `serverless.template`, but at deploy the code is recompiled and the template regenerated missing the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify either a policy or a role but not both. When you specify a policy a role is created with that policy attached to the role.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution!